# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, spyder

When I'm importing TensorFlow with Spyder as so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I then face the following error:

> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'**

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: how did you install tensorflow? are you using python or Anaconda. Also what is your python version. Try to provide as much info as possible in your question, so people can help you.

Comment: Installed TensorFlow thru Pip install tensorflow, I'm using Anaconda, Python version is 3.6, Operating System Windows 10...

Comment: @pavanU Your problem is you're using Python 3.6 and as of now only Python 3.5 is supported on Windows. One alternative is to create a conda environment for Python=3.5 as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419795/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-anaconda-python-3-6/43420579#43420579)

Answer (score 7):

Since you plan to use tensforflow with Anaconda, you need to install it through Anaconda. It is advisable to do this as follows:

1. `C:> conda create -n tensorflow`
2. `C:> activate tensorflow`
3. `C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

It is recommended you create a virtual environment as shown above as this makes managing different versions of Python easier. All packages you install (in this case Tensorflow) will become available whenever you activate this virtual environment, and they will not conflict with other versions of Python you may have.

Comment: Installation is completed successfully.. Command Prompt is working fine for me .. Facing issue with GUI only . Like Spyder / Jupyter

Comment: @pavanU did you find a way to use tensorflow in Spyder GUI?

Comment: I got the same error in Jupyter notebook, and resolved by installing tensorflow to Anaconda from command prompt as: C:\anaconda3\Scripts>pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: I have the following error while following your instructions : `tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: @ThePassenger what OS and version of python are you using? Also try `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: Is it possible to use a GUI like Spyder? Or do you have to use the command prompt for everything except running scripts?