# how to install tensorflow on anaconda python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, python-wheel

I installed the new version python 3.6 with the anaconda package. However i am not able to install tensorflow. Always receive the error that

tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

How can I install tensorflow on anaconda (python 3.6)?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `cp35` indicates that your wheel is for `CPython3.5` -- The different version might be biting you and google may not have released a wheel for 3.6 yet.  It's possible that to get it working you'll need to build the whole thing yourself ...

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7552)

Comment: is there something wrong with `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`?

Answer (score 38):

**UPDATE:** TensorFlow supports Python 3.6 on Windows since version 1.2.0 (see the [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#release-120))

---

TensorFlow only supports Python 3.5 64-bit as of now. Support for Python 3.6 is a work in progress and you can track it [here](http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6999) as well as chime in the discussion.

The only alternative to use Python 3.6 with TensorFlow on Windows currently is building TF from source.

If you don't want to uninstall your Anaconda distribution for Python 3.6 and install a previous release you can create a conda environment for Python=3.5 as in:

`conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: I struggled with pip to install also the tensorflow-gpu dependencies (for version 1.11). The anaconda repository give it along with the installation. Therefore, I recommend to use conda to install the package: `conda install -n myenv tensorflow-gpu==1.11.0` (or any version). This way also cudnn and cudotoolkit are installed to the conda environment in the correct version.

Comment: is there something wrong with `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`?

Answer (score 13):

This is what I did for Installing Anaconda Python 3.6 version and Tensorflow on Window 10 64bit.And It was success!

1. Download [Anaconda Python 3.6 version for Window 64bit](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).
2. Create a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:

   ```
   C:> conda create -n tensorflow
   ```
3. Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:

   ```
   C:> activate tensorflow
   (tensorflow)C:>  # Your prompt should change
   ```
4. Download “tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl” from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). (For my case, the file will be located in “C:\Users\Joshua\Downloads” once after downloaded).
5. Install the Tensorflow  by using following command:

   ```
   (tensorflow)C:>pip install C:\Users\Joshua\Downloads\ tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
   ```

This is what I got after the installing:
 [image]

6. Validate installation by entering following command in your Python environment:

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
   sess = tf.Session()
   print(sess.run(hello))
   ```

If the output you got is 'Hello, TensorFlow!',that means you have successfully install your Tensorflow.

Comment: there is no GPU 1.2 version  there :)

Comment: Yes, this is CPU version

Comment: is there something wrong with `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`?

Answer (score 6):

Simple Way from Scratch.

1. Download Anaconda from https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe
2. Install Anaconda by double clicking it.
3. Open anaconda prompt by searching anaconda in windows search and type the following command while being connected to internet.

   A. `conda create -n tensorflow_env python=3.6`

   B. `conda activate tensorflow_env`

   C. `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

Step C will take time. After install type `python` in conda prompt and type

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

If no error is found your installation is successful.

Comment: what if `conda activate tensorflow` does nothing?

Comment: As far as I can remember (but not sure) conda activate tensorflow does nothing. conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow will only install tensorflow.

Comment: why are you telling us how to activate an env? all one needs is,`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`, no?

Comment: It's about to install tensorflow as well as to activate the environment. Both.

Answer (score 2):

According to :https://anaconda.org/intel/tensorflow

To install this package with conda run:

```
conda install -c intel tensorflow
```

pip install 
To install this package with pip:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/intel/simple tensorflow
```

Comment: is there something wrong with `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `conda install tensorflow` worked perfect for me!

Comment: did you try `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`?

Answer (score 0):

I use this method as told by one of the user:
This is what I did for Installing Anaconda Python 3.6 version and Tensorflow on Window 10 64bit.And It was success!

Go to https://www.continuum.io/downloads to download Anaconda Python 3.6 version for Window 64bit.
Create a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:

C:> conda create -n tensorflow
Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:

C:> activate tensorflow (tensorflow)C:> # Your prompt should change
Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/enter code here download “tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl”. (For my case, the file will be located in “C:\Users\Joshua\Downloads” once after downloaded)
Install the Tensorflow by using following command:

(tensorflow)C:>pip install C:\Users\Joshua\Downloads\ tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

but nothing happens in the prompt. It starts from the new line with the tensorflow as if nothing was written. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

## Python 3.6

pip install https://anaconda.org/intel/tensorflow/1.2.1/download/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

Source: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimized-tensorflow-wheel-now-available

Comment: This is for Linux operating system, it is gonna be useful to indicate these when sharing information.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Python 3.7 for Windows, and only install Python 3.6.0
then you will have no problem or receive the error message:

import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Answer (score 0):

This works for me CPU installation

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow # for python 2.x

pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow # for python 3.x
```

Answer (score -1):

For Windows 10 with Anaconda 4.4 Python 3.6:

1st step) `conda create -n tensorflow  python=3.6`

2nd step) `activate tensorflow`

3rd step) `pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: For GPU:
3rd step) (tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: The third step didn't work for me. I got the following error: "... is not a supported wheel on this platform". Is it something to do with x32 and x64 versions?

Comment: If I try conda install tensorflow, I get the following error:
PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-32 channels: 
  - tensorflow

Comment: for GPU, use this command: conda install -c anaconda -y tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0

Comment: why are you telling us how to activate an env? all one needs is,`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`, no?

Answer (score -1):

conda create -n tensorflow_gpuenv tensorflow-gpu

Or

type the command pip install c:.*.whl in command prompt (cmd).

Comment: why are you telling us how to activate an env? all one needs is,`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`, no?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this [link](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) :

- Go to https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual and click the “Download” -button
- Download the Python 3.7 64-Bit (x86) Installer
- Run the downloaded bash script (.sh) file to begin the installation. See here for more details.
- -When prompted with the question “Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda<2 or 3> install location to PATH in your /home//.bashrc ?”, answer “Yes”. If you enter “No”, you must manually add the path to Anaconda or conda will not work.

Select Windows or linked base command, In my case I have used Linux  :

**Create a new Anaconda virtual environment**
**Open a new Terminal window**

Type the following command: *The above will create a new virtual environment with* name tensorflow

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.8

 conda activate tensorflow
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why are you telling us how to activate an env? all one needs is,`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`, no?

Comment: @CharlieParker if you have multiple evn you can activate and dectivate  different env one next to other.

Answer (score -1):

I will simply leave this here because none of the other approaches worked for me. Also, I can look it up myself when I need it for new devices.

## THIS IS THE WAY IT WORKS:

1. Install Anaconda
2. Open Anaconda Prompt
3. `conda create --name tensorflow`
4. `conda activate tensorflow`
5. Search with `conda search tensorflow` for all available TensorFlow versions
6. Choose the one you need (usually the newest one)
7. Explicitly name the version now (otherwise it happened to me that version `1.14` was installed): `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=YOUR_VERSION`
8. Open Anaconda, choose the new environment and install Spyder
9. Install  [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
10. Download [msvcp140.dll](https://www.dll-files.com/download/7b92a6cb5d2cad407c457ab12d2b211d/msvcp140.dll.html?c=WmllUGFUQTg5Uk5iTDVaUithdDNoUT09) and add the `.dll`-File to the `Windows\System32` folder

Now it should work like a charm!

## TROUBLESHOOTING:

If it still doesn't work, try this, it worked for me:

Open Anaconda-Prompt:

1. Create an environment with `Python 3.6` like this: `conda create --name tensorflow_env python=3.6`
2. `conda activate tensorflow`
3. Steps 6. and 6. from the list above
4. `conda install tensorflow=YOUR_VERSION`(not forge, just like this!)
5. Now do steps 8, 9, 10 from above

## TENSORFLOW GPU:

If you want to use your GPU, do it the same way as described above, with the only difference to install `tensorflow-gpu` instead if `tensorflow`.

And, you must install the newest NVIDIA driver for your GPU, you can find and choose the right one [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

(Yes, in TF 2 there's both, a CPU and GPU support, in the "normal" library. However, if you install `tensorflow-gpu` via conda, it installs the CUDA and cudNN etc. you need automatically for you - also the right versions. This way easier and faster.)

Comment: why are you telling us how to activate an env? all one needs is,`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`, no?