# tensorflow installation issue using anaconda

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install `tensorflow` using anaconda but followed the following approach and failed.

```
 C:\>activate tensorflow

        (tensorflow) C:\>conda create -n tensorflow


        CondaValueError: Value error: prefix already exists: C:\Users\pirates\Anaconda3\
        envs\tensorflow



        (tensorflow) C:\>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.google
        apis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
        tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platf
        orm.

        (tensorflow) C:\>
```

I am not able to install `tensorflow` with `conda` command .. what do I do?

I had installed anaconda 1.5 for python 3.6.0

Please somebody help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install tensorflow on anaconda python 3.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419795/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-anaconda-python-3-6)

Comment: it seems that you already have an env named `tensorflow`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to my as a python version incompatibility ,try to install python 3.5 and then run tensorflow installation again.