# Installed tensorflow, but pycharm ignores it

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I installed tensorflow by(answer from Joshua):
[how to install tensorflow on anaconda python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419795/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-anaconda-python-3-6)
 If I test it in cmd:

```
D:\>python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC 
v.1
900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import tensorflow
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2017-07-14 16:21:53.235367: W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow-
r1.2\tensorflow\cor
e\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled 
to us
e SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed 
up C
PU computations.
2017-07-14 16:21:53.508199: W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow-
r1.2\tensorflow\cor
e\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled 
to us
e SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed 
up
CPU computations.
2017-07-14 16:21:53.511766: W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow-
r1.2\tensorflow\cor
e\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled 
to us
e SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed 
up
CPU computations.
2017-07-14 16:21:53.515734: W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow-
r1.2\tensorflow\cor
e\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled 
to us
e SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could 
speed u
p CPU computations.
2017-07-14 16:21:53.517818: W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow-
r1.2\tensorflow\cor
e\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled 
to us
e SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could 
speed u
p CPU computations.
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

So this shoulb be ok....but if I try t repeat this test in pycharm(even after I restarted pycharm):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `conda's` virtual environment on pycharm

Go to File, Default Setting and under project interpreter select the anaconda one.

If you use `pip` to install packages, be sure that `pip` is pointing towards the right python instance.

Answer (score 8):

just install tensorflow from the project settings. You don't need anaconda.

[image]

Comment: nb. to get to Project Interpreter in PyCharm: File | Settings | Project Interpreter

Comment: I think there is no that option anymore. Its so sad that none of these ides can work properly.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a new project you should select Anaconda's environment as python Interpreter.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, will there be problems if I installed other packages using with pip?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue ( I am using  pycharm 2018 3.5 in windows 10)
I used `(venv) D:\>pip install tensorflow --upgrade` in terminal to update my tensor flow

and wait (It is time consuming) to get this:

> Successfully installed absl-py-0.7.1 astor-0.7.1 gast-0.2.2 grpcio-1.19.0 h5py-2.9.0 keras-applications-1.0.7 keras-preprocessing-1.0.9 markdown-3.0.1 mock-2.0.0 numpy-1.16.2 pbr-5.
>   1.3 protobuf-3.7.0 six-1.12.0 tensorboard-1.13.1 tensorflow-1.13.1 tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.14.1 wheel-0.33.1*

and it solved!!!