# Installed tensorflow in an anaconda env but cannot import (Tensorflow 1.15, Python 3.6, PyCharm)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I recently created an environment in PyCharm using anaconda and i'm using Python version 3.6. I want to import tensorflow but unfortunately i keep getting the error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'". I installed tensorflow versions (1.20 & 1.15) on my environment with no major issues, i also tried and added both in the Project Interpreter window successfully but when i run my program i keep getting that error. Anyone know a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error, you have installed everything in one environment but you work in another. 
Try installing tensorflow from another command line (in another shell).

Comment: What is your IDE?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm

Comment: Have you followed this guide to install tensorflow in virtual environment?
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
or just installed it via PyCharm terminal "pip install tensorflow"?

Comment: This may be your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48611380/11524604

Comment: I created an anaconda virtual environment because i also wanted to install "Librosa" and i couldn't install it using pip. The tensorflow package is there but when im trying to import it i get an error

Comment: Try in PyCharm terminal:
"pip show tensorflow"
to know your version and whether it is installed

Comment: Make sure the proper project interpreter is selected: PyCharm File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter

Comment: It is, but i think there's a stupid mistake here that i just noticed. I'm new to python, does the code file for example "example.py" needs to be inside the interpreter folder?

Comment: Your example.py is in project folder and interpreter can be in any other folder. In Settings you choose a path to interpreter. When focus in on your code try Ctrl+Shift+F10 (if you're on mac I think it's the same) to quickly run it.

Comment: PyCharm File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter - press cog symbol near path to interpreter and select "Show all", try other interpreters
Does your terminal where you print commands show just path to folder: e.g. "D:\_Scripts\Python\temp>" or does it have "(venv)" in front?

Comment: for some reason it has venv infront thats why i was wondering if the file path makes any difference

Comment: (venv) means that everything that you install via this terminal will make changes only to virtual environment. That's where all your installations went. And you are trying to run a script via common interpreter where no installations were made.
In the upper right corner of PyCharm click on name of your file (example.py) -> Edit Configurations. From there select another interpreter