# about installing new version of TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Win10 / Python 3.6 / Anaconda Navigator. I installed latest version of TensorFlow via Anaconda Prompt. I saw the message of "Succesfully installed ... tensorboard-1.6.0 tensorflow-1.6.0 ..." on the Anaconda Prompt. But in the jupyter nb (after "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.**version**)") I take a result "1.2.1" . On the Anaconda Navigator; Environments tab, there is same result "tensorflow version 1.2.1".
Could you explain my problem?

Comment: perhaps you could remove the old version and install the newer version?

Comment: I find the explanation I'm looking for in Adriano's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419795/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-anaconda-python-3-6?answertab=votes#tab-top .