# Tensorflow Installation Error in Conda Environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda

I am trying to install Tenserflow through [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/). When I run:

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

I get the following error:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (459.1 MB)
     |                                | 276 kB 29 kB/s eta 4:21:25ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
```

Comment: Try the instructions at https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install tensorflow on anaconda python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419795/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-anaconda-python-3-6)

Comment: if you are using conda install Tensorflow through it with "conda install tensorflow", avoid using pip inside conda environment when you can...

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link given below. This has helped me and my friends a lot of times.

https://youtu.be/O8yye2AHCOk